# Is there a call_user_func() equivalent to create a new class instance?

Tags: php, class, php4

How can I create a class with a given array of arguments to be sent to the constructor? Something along the lines of:

```
class a {
    var $args = false;
    function a() {$this->args = func_get_args();}
}

$a = call_user_func_array('new a',array(1,2,3));
print_r($a->args);
```

Ideally this needs to work, without modification to the class, in both PHP4 and PHP5. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to do it like this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Skilldrick: in my case, trying to implement a simple dependency injection container.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call the constructor with call\_user\_func\_array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409237/how-to-call-the-constructor-with-call-user-func-array-in-php)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[ReflectionClass:newInstance()](http://docs.php.net/reflectionclass.newinstance) (or newInstanceArgs()) let's you do that.

e.g.

```
class Foo {
  public function __construct() {  
    $p = func_get_args();
    echo 'Foo::__construct(', join(',', $p), ') invoked';
  }
}

$rc = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
$foo = $rc->newInstanceArgs( array(1,2,3,4,5) );
```

edit: without ReflectionClass and probably php4 compatible (sorry, no php4 at hand right now)

```
class Foo {
  public function __construct() {  
    $p = func_get_args();
    echo 'Foo::__construct(', join(',', $p), ') invoked';
  }
}

$class = 'Foo';
$rc = new $class(1,2,3,4);
```

speed comparison: 
Since the speed of reflection has been mentioned here's a little (synthetic) test

```
define('ITERATIONS', 100000);

class Foo {
  protected $something;
  public function __construct() {
    $p = func_get_args();
    $this->something = 'Foo::__construct('.join(',', $p).')';
  }
}

$rcStatic=new ReflectionClass('Foo'); 
$fns = array(
  'direct new'=>function() { $obj = new Foo(1,2,3,4); },
  'indirect new'=>function() { $class='Foo'; $obj = new $class(1,2,3,4); }, 
  'reflection'=>function() { $rc=new ReflectionClass('Foo'); $obj = $rc->newInstanceArgs( array(1,2,3,4) ); },
  'reflection cached'=>function() use ($rcStatic) { $obj = $rcStatic->newInstanceArgs( array(1,2,3,4) ); },
);


sleep(1);
foreach($fns as $name=>$f) {
  $start = microtime(true);
  for($i=0; $i<ITERATIONS; $i++) {
    $f();
  }
  $end = microtime(true);
  echo $name, ': ', $end-$start, "\n";
  sleep(1);
}
```

which prints on my (not so fast) notebook

```
direct new: 0.71329689025879
indirect new: 0.75944685935974
reflection: 1.3510940074921
reflection cached: 1.0181720256805
```

Isn't that bad, is it?

Comment: Reflection are supported in PHP5 only, but this is the way I would do it.

Comment: I would recommend against using any reflection in production code. It's very slow.

Comment: Shame it's PHP5 only, but thanks. Will probably use this with a fallback to an eval statement for PHP4. Speed isn't too much of an issue for my uses.

Comment: Before using eval() you really should test the new $class(1,2,3) thing with php4 first. I'm quite certain it will work. And the factory is a great, basic pattern - definitely worth the time to read it up ;-)

Comment: Are there any downsides to using the `new $class($args)` method?

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at the [Factory Method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and check out [this example](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method/php/1)

From Wikipedia:

> The factory method pattern is an
>   object-oriented design pattern. Like
>   other creational patterns, it deals
>   with the problem of creating objects
>   (products) without specifying the
>   exact class of object that will be
>   created.

If you don't want to use a dedicated Factory for this, you could still [wrap Volker's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929108/is-there-a-calluserfunc-equivalent-to-create-a-new-class-instance/1929133#1929133) into a function, e.g.

```
/**
 * Creates a new object instance
 *
 * This method creates a new object instance from from the passed $className
 * and $arguments. The second param $arguments is optional.
 *
 * @param  String $className class to instantiate
 * @param  Array  $arguments arguments required by $className's constructor
 * @return Mixed  instance of $className
 */
function createInstance($className, array $arguments = array())
{
    if(class_exists($className)) {
        return call_user_func_array(array(
            new ReflectionClass($className), 'newInstance'), 
            $arguments);
    }
    return false;
}
```