# How to call the constructor with call_user_func_array in PHP

Tags: php, constructor

How could I call the constructor of a class with call_user_func_array

It is not possible to do :

```
$obj = new $class();
call_user_func_array(array($obj, '__construct'), $args);
```

because if the constructor has parameters, the *new* will fail.

Constraint : I do not control the classes that I have to instantiate, nor can I modify them.

Don't ask me why I want to do this crazy thing, this is a crazy test.

Comment: See various solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929108/is-there-a-call-user-func-equivalent-to-create-a-new-class-instance

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You can use [reflection](http://php.net/reflection) like:

```
$reflect  = new ReflectionClass($class);
$instance = $reflect->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

---

As of PHP 5.6.0, the [`...` operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) can also be used for this purpose.

```
$instance = new $class(...$args);
```

---

```
if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.6.0', '>=')){
    $instance = new $class(...$args);
} else {
    $reflect  = new ReflectionClass($class);
    $instance = $reflect->newInstanceArgs($args);
}
```

Comment: This will fail lower than 5.6.0 with following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'