# Call class and pass constructor parameters in PHP

Tags: php, oop, class, function

I know how to use:

```
call_user_func_array(array($className, $methodName), array($_POST)) ;
```

To call a function in my class and send it parameters.

But how would I go about calling just the class and passing it parameters that go into the __constructor?

Doing it manually I'd do:

```
$myTable = new Supertable(array('columnA', 'columnB'), 5, 'Some string') ;
```

Which would work. What function do I need to achieve something similar to what call_user_func_array does?

Here it is in the full context of what I'm doing:

```
function __autoload($classname) {
    @include $classname.'.php' ;
}

$className = 'supertable' ;
$methodName = 'main' ;

if(class_exists($className, true)) {
    if(method_exists($className, $methodName)) {
        $reflection = new ReflectionMethod($className, $methodName) ;

        if($reflection->isPublic()){
            call_user_func_array(array($className, $methodName), array($_POST)) ;
        } elseif($reflection->isPrivate()) {
            echo '<span class="state">Private</span> method <span class="methodname">'.$methodName.'</span> can not be accessed directly.' ;
        } elseif($reflection->isProtected()) {
        echo '<span class="state">Protected</span> method <span class="methodname">'.$methodName.'</span> can not be accessed directly.' ;
        }

    } else {
        echo 'The method <span class="methodname">'.$methodName.'</span> does not exist.' ;
    }
} else {
    echo 'The class <span class="classname">'.$className.'</span> does not exist.' ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my own question here:

[How to call the constructor with call_user_func_array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409237/how-to-call-the-constructor-with-call-user-func-array-in-php)

For reference, I altered my script like so:

```
function __autoload($classname)
{
    @include $classname.'.php' ;
}

$className = 'supertable' ;
$methodName = '' ;

if(class_exists($className, true))
{
if(method_exists($className, $methodName))
{
    $reflection = new ReflectionMethod($className, $methodName) ;

    if($reflection->isPublic())
    {
        call_user_func_array(array($className, $methodName), array($_POST)) ;
    }
    elseif($reflection->isPrivate())
    {
        echo '<span class="state">Private</span> method <span class="methodname">'.$methodName.'</span> can not be accessed directly.' ;
    }
    elseif($reflection->isProtected())
    {
        echo '<span class="state">Protected</span> method <span class="methodname">'.$methodName.'</span> can not be accessed directly.' ;
    }

} else {
    $reflect  = new ReflectionClass($className);
    $reflect->newInstanceArgs(array($_POST));
}
} else {
echo 'The class <span class="classname">'.$className.'</span> does not exist.' ;
}
```

So if the class exists but no method is given it calls the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If that is **exactly** what you need, I don't see the whole point, for 2 reasons:

1. You can call it easily this way:

   ```
   new $className($_POST);
   ```
2. `$_POST` is a superglobal and (I'm sure you know this) doesn't need to be passed as a parameter in order to be accessible.

Comment: it is part of an AJAX routing system I'm trying to make. Yes, I'm just testing and messing around with it at the moment, something specific will be passed in the end e.g. $_POST['mydata'].