# Initiate a class instance with dynamic parameters?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a new class instance with dynamic parameters e.g.:

```
$controller = 'className';
$parameters = array('hello', 'world');
new $controller($parameters);
```

Except I would like the parameters to be passed to the class naturally, like they would if I called a method via `call_user_func_array();`, I want to avoid having to pass the parameters in an array.

Is there any way to initiate a class while effectively calling `call_user_func_array();` on the constructor? Or even to prevent the automatic running of the constructor so that I can run it via `call_user_func_array();` with the properties as an array?

My actual code right now is:

```
if(!class_exists($controller)) require('controllers/' . $controller . '.php');
return new $controller();
```

I could pass an array of parameters to the constructor like `$controller($parameters)`, but then they would all be in a single array, not as individual parameters.

The full file source can be viewed in context here: https://github.com/pyrokinetic/mfw/blob/master/libraries/load.lib.php

Comment: parametrised constructor

Comment: Not sure about your needs, but you can create a static function in your class names `getInstance` which receive an array of parameters and then, call the static method with your `call_user_func_array`. You can mix this with magic `__set` and `__get` to avoid a specific signature of the constructor.

Comment: Check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409237/how-to-call-the-constructor-with-call-user-func-array-in-php

Comment: @Wicked Thanks, make it an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$reflect  = new ReflectionClass($class);
$instance = $reflect->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409237/how-to-call-the-constructor-with-call-user-func-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Get your stuff from Router

$class = "Home";
$method = "Welcome";
$params = array(
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'John'
);

// Dispatch

$app = new $class();
call_user_func_array(array($app, $method), $params);
```

This way $params is array when you hand it to call_user_func_array(), but inside your instantiated controller / method you would not have $params as one array variable, but every key from your $params array will be seperate variable.
Is this what you need?

Comment: It is kind of what I need, but I wanted to have that exact same affect applied to the constructor (which is called on the first line when you say `new $class();`)

Comment: If you want the same effect but in one line like this: new $class($params); then its not possible. You can do it like described above, or using PHP Reflection Classes. What do you mean exactly when you say you want the same effect applied to the constructor?

Comment: The reflection class method is what I was after, see Wicked's comment on the question. Thanks.

Comment: Hey can you just tell me what is the difference with call_user_func_array as I wrote above, and his example with Reflection? I wrote nice little router and I used call_user_func_array, can you tell me are those the same or there are some differences? You can check my router and the way I dispatch request here: https://github.com/matijabozic/php_router#dispatching-request They look the same to me. They both invoke a method, are there differences? Thanks!

Comment: What he's doing with the reflection class is achieving the same result as you are using `call_user_func_array()`, except it's being used on the class's `__constructor()` which isn't possible with `call_user_func_array()` because the constructor will have already ran from when you initialised the class.

Comment: Ohooo thats it, I didn't think about that, had no problems with call_user_func_array so I just used it. Will probably use Reflection then. Thanks! If you run into problems with order of your params inside a method, then remember me and revisit link I put here in comments, that one bugged me for quite some time ha, ha... Thanks again!

Comment: Will do, I've also written my own PHP router which uses regex routes ;) https://github.com/pyrokinetic/mfw/blob/master/libraries/router.lib.php