# send more than one argument

Tags: php, get, arguments

wanted to know how I can pass all arguments ('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3') for MyComponents
I tried with 'func_get_args' Components in class but could not

```
class Components
    function ini( $component )

class MyComponents
    function ini( $arg1 , $arg2 , $arg3 )

$components-> ini( 'MyComponent' , 'arg1' , 'arg2' , 'arg3' )
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide code that would work instead of a few sample lines? Why you would use func_get_args when you can use the variables you're having the arguments assigned to I don't know.

Comment: I have nothing relevant because it could not start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/function.call-user-func-array.php) for this.

Either provide an array of arguments to `Components::ini()` or get the array via `func_get_args()` and then pass them with `call_user_func_array()` along.

If you are interested in constructing them with a variable arguments, use a `ReflectionClass` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2409288/1557526).

Comment: the idea is that you can spend according to MyComponents... example: `MyComponents1( var1 , var2 )` , `MyComponents2( var1 , var2 , var3 )`... not be a set number of parameters would be varied

Comment: @PapaCharlie And where exactly doesn't my answer satisfy your needs? Sorry but your question is quite vague/unclear. If possible, please provide some code that shows exactly what you want to achieve and where your current attempts failed you