# PHP - how do I pass args to a class constructor while using variable class name?

Tags: php, parameters, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a call_user_func() equivalent to create a new class instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929108/is-there-a-call-user-func-equivalent-to-create-a-new-class-instance)

I instansiate my class like this:

```
$className = 'varClassName';
$validator = new $className;
```

But I want to pass an array as an argument to the class constructor. I thought the following might work:

```
$className = 'varClassName(array('min'=>2, 'max'=50))';
$validator = new $className;
```

However this results in an error that the class cannot be found. So how can I pass args to a class constructor while using variable class name?

Comment: This is not possible without eval(). Why do you need it? It smells of a design flaw

Comment: It's possible without `eval()`. See below. But I agree that this clearly indicates a design flaw. And a major one at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$className = 'varClassName';
$validator = new $className(array('min'=>2, 'max'=>50));
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is really what the OP's asking for. But we will see

Comment: This is not even possible in PHP, I wonder why the OP did accept this as an answer - an even got three upvotes. *"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'"* - this is fatal - see: http://eval.in/3599

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice befor that I've made a typo (in the array definition, I wrote `=` instead of `=>`). Now it works. Thank you for noticing. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [ReflectionClass](http://www.php.net/manual/de/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php). You can do something like this:

```
$rc = new ReflectionClass("YourClass");
$obj = $rc->newInstanceArgs(array(...));
```

This is probably the best way to do this, but it's a fairly new addition to PHP. The alternative would be to use `eval()` but I refuse to write code like this. ;)

Comment: You're right. I was a little confused when I answered. I modified my answer...maybe that helps better. :)

Answer (score 0):

You do like this: `$validator = new $className($array);`