# Initiate object through an array

Tags: php, arrays, object

Basically my setup is that I have a lot of objects that I want to create. What type of object it will become is dependent on one variable, which is the type. So originally I would have to do many if statements, so to shorten it I created an array, but I am running in to the problem of being able to create the actual object through the array.

Here is what I had originally:

```
if($object->type = 'text')
{
    $object_new = new Text();
} elseif($object->type = 'image') {
    $object_new = new Image();
} ....
```

But what I wanted to do is:

```
$all_objects = array('text'=> new Text(), 'image' => new Image(), ...);
$object_new = $all_objects($object->type);
```

Which would shorten my code by a lot as well as make it more efficient.

Comment: It should work, but you need `$all_objects[...]` instead of `()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no further dependencies to these object, you can simply do

```
$className = $object->type;
$instance = new $className;
```

If you need more sophisticated creation logic, you can put the creation code in Lambdas and call those then, e.g.

```
$allTypes = array(
    'text' => function($string) { return new Text($string); },
    'Image' => function($path) { return new Image($path); }
);
$instance = call_user_func_array($allTypes[$object->type], array($argument1));
```

Or you create a Factory object and put a switch/case into it:

```
class Factory
{
    public function create($type)
    {
        switch ($type)
        {
            case 'text':
                return new Text;
            case 'image':
                return Image($this->create('foo'));
            case 'foo':
                return new Foo;
            default:
                throw new Exception('No clue what to create');
        }
    }
}
```

Also checkout [Is there a call_user_func() equivalent to create a new class instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929108/is-there-a-call-user-func-equivalent-to-create-a-new-class-instance)

Comment: Heck, you can even just do `$instance = new $object->type;`.

Comment: One needs to be carefull though, using this with *__autoload*-ing and case-sensitive filesystems. (at least for the first method ;))

Answer (score 0):

Making an array of `$all_objects` will cause more problems.  When you get an element from there, it would be a reference, so each time you accessed an element, it'd be the same as the last time you accessed it.  (example: http://codepad.org/Z4B7glk9)

Instead try something like this (Class names in PHP are case insensitive):

```
$object_new = new $object->type();
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/Hq09jkHz

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
$types = array('image', 'text', 'link', 'somethingelse');
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $$type = new ucfirst($type);
}
```

This means:

```
$image         = new Image;
$text          = new Text;
$link          = new Link;
$somethingelse = new Somethingelse;
```

Of course, you need to have *Image*, *Text*, *Link* and *Somethingelse* classes.

Comment: I think he just wants to make an instance of a class using a string as the name.  I don't think he needs to make instances of all of the classes.